# What is the probability of time.time() generating the same result in a loop?

Tags: python, performance, atomic

Assume having a simple application running on an average machine *(4vCore ~3GHz)* implementing the following code:

```
import time
for i in range(99):
    print(time.time())
```

Which will generate a series of high precision timestamps

```
1630912866.957683
1630912866.957693
1630912866.957696
1630912866.9576986
1630912866.9577005
1630912866.9577026
1630912866.9577048
1630912866.9577065
1630912866.9577084
1630912866.9577103
```

What is the probability of these timestamps colliding and what are the factors influencing it?

Comment: That is an incredibly broad question and the only answer is "it depends". The real question is: why do you need to know? What are you trying to achieve, because there's probably a better way to go about it?

Comment: Syscalls take some time, typically around 1-2 microseconds overhead simply due the fact it is a syscall. Querying clock takes probably 10times longer. Plus you have overhead due to Python. On the other hand typical clocks have +-1 microsecond precision. Therefore it is extremely unlikely, effectively 0% probability, that two consecutive time measurements return the same time. That of course depends on your machine and OS, since some clocks have 1 second precision.

Comment: I guess you are using `time.time()` to make a time difference between two frames, and then you get a `ZeroDivisionError` when you calculate the framerate. In that case, better implement a max framerate: if the time difference is 0, then wait some time (for example 0.0167s to get 60 FPS) and update the time difference.

Comment: @freakish it is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for: what does it depend on and what the dynamics are. Thanks for giving more insights. If you wish post a proper answer, I'd be glad

Answer (score 1):

You can get the frequence of it happening by running this code at the beginning of your program, or at random intervals, preferably in another thread to do not interrupt your program consumption:

```py
import time
number = 1000000
l = []
prev = time.time()
for x in range(number):
    if time.time() != prev:
        l.append(time.time())
    prev = time.time()

    
frequence = len(l)/number
```

Just keep in mind that the framerate will change according to the computer you are using, the application requests, even the other running applications...